# How can I create a random color Linear Gradient so that the random color generated is constant for each profile?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topRight,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.orange,
                    Colors.red,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              child: const CircleAvatar(
                radius: 70,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                child: Text(
                  "S",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

I want the profile color created for each user to be produced only once and remain constant.

```
body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topRight,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.orange,
                    Colors.red,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              child: const CircleAvatar(
                radius: 70,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                child: Text(
                  "S",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: If there is some unique information associated with the profile -- for example, a user ID or an email address -- you can hash that information and use the resulting value as the basis for generating the gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generate linear gradient which will be unique for each initial

```
LinearGradient getGredient(String inital){
      List<Color> colors = [
        Colors.red,
        Colors.blue,
        Colors.green,
        Colors.purple,
        Colors.orange,
        Colors.pink,
        Colors.yellow,
        Colors.teal,
        Colors.indigo,
        Colors.brown,
        Colors.cyan,
        Colors.lime,
        Colors.lightBlue,
        Colors.lightGreen,
        Colors.deepOrange,
        Colors.deepPurple,
        Colors.amber,
        Colors.blueGrey,
        Colors.brown,
        Colors.cyan,
        Colors.deepOrange,
        Colors.deepPurple,
        Colors.green,
        Colors.indigo,
        Colors.lightBlue,
        Colors.lightGreen,
        Colors.lime,
        Colors.orange,
        Colors.pink,
        Colors.purple,
        Colors.red,
        Colors.teal,
        Colors.yellow,
      ];
      int index = inital.codeUnitAt(0) % colors.length;
      return LinearGradient(
        colors: [colors[index], colors[index + 1]],
        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Try this:

```
...
import 'dart:math' as math;
...
var randomColor = Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
...
Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: Alignment.topRight,
                  colors: [
                    randomColor,
                    randomColor
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Your code works and creates colors, but it has two problems: the range of colors created is small, and the second problem is that the color created is not constant.
For the first problem, if it is used in this way, it will have a better response.

Comment: var randomColor = Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 255).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
  var randomColor1 = Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);

Comment: colors: [
                    randomColor1,
                    randomColor,
                  ],